# Prove the following corollary.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

Let $X$ be a Banach space, $Y$ be a norm linear space, $(A_n)\in \Bbb B(X,Y)$ be such that for every $x\in X, ||(A_n-A)x||\rightarrow0$ for some $A\in \Bbb B(X,Y)$. If $K:X\rightarrow Y$ is a compact operator, then prove that $||(A_n-A)K||\rightarrow 0$

Comment: Pointwise convergence implies uniform convergence on compact sets for continuous maps.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer can you elaborate more? How to apply this clue?

Comment: First correct the condition on $K$, the codomain of $K$ must be $X$ for the composition to be defined. Then recall the definition of a compact operator. (There are several equivalent definitions, the one using $T(B)$ where $B$ is the unit ball of the domain is the useful one.)